# Collapsing headers after groupby with different aggregations per column

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a groupby with different aggregations per column like so

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'C': np.random.randn(4)})
```

df

```
   A  B         C
0  1  1  0.362838
1  1  2  0.227877
2  2  3  1.267767
3  2  4 -0.562860
```

then

```
df.groupby('A').agg({'B': ['min', 'max'], 'C': 'sum'})
```

gives the output

```
       B         C
  | min max |   sum
A |         |
1 |  1   2  | 0.590716
2 |  3   4  | 0.704907
```

I can now access then minimum of column B via

```
df['B']['min']
```

What I would like to do is simplify the headers to be

```
  | B |   C
1 | 1 | 0.590716
2 | 3 | 0.704907
```

where B is set to `df['B']['min']` so I can call my columns again using `df['B']` and `df['C']`

Comment: Looks like you don't need max value of B, is that correct ?

Comment: yes, that is correct. I do not need it in the final output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Improved answer with help of DisneylandSC**

Multiindex column can be first removed by using `.drop()` and then `.droplevel()` function.

```
df.drop(columns=['B','max'],level=1).droplevel(level=1,axis=1)
```

---

**Old answer:**

To remove multiindex column from your final dataset you can use `.drop()` and specify `level`.

```
df.drop(columns=['B','max'],level=1).T.droplevel(1).T
```

Comment: I do need the max value of B for some calculation in between, just not in the final output.

Comment: I have added another answer where you can remove that 'max' column after you performed calculations.

Comment: .droplevel seems to do it. Although you don't need to transpose the df. Instead droplevel allows you to set the axis via  keyword .droplevel(level=1, axis=1).